# Tomcat_user.xml changes are not affecting localhost login?

Tags: tomcat

I've made changes to my username and password in my Tomcat_user.xml but for some reason the changes to the username and password are not affecting the login windows. I try entering my new username and password it's not accepting them. Only the old username and password which were no longer included in the Tomcat_user.xml seem to work. On top of that none of the rolename like "manager" or "manager-gui" I inputted into Tomcat_user.xml seem to work leaving me unable to autodeploy my projects onto the server. This also isn't the first time it's happened. What's going on? Can someone tell me why this could be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you restart the tomcat?

Comment: I did that and it still didn't work.

Comment: It also wasn't the first time it happened. But this time, nothing I do seem to be taking any effect.

Comment: What is your need? To access manager-gui?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable a tomcat user for the manager-gui, add the following code to the `tomcat_users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Comment: I made that change but it's not taking affecting my loginpage. My need is to fix whatever is broken. Right now whatever changes I made inside the tomcat_user.xml isn't working. And all the projects I had under my webapp folder aren't autodeploying onto the server nor are the libraries that make them support other languages working. I'm just trying to understand what is the cause of it all.

Comment: If you messed up with a lot of files the best thing maybe just to download and setup a brand new tomcat installation. Otherwise, the above code should enable you to access the manager.

Comment: Will I still be able to keep all my projects and libraries in there too though?

Comment: It is easy to deploy applications. Just backup the libraries you need and you are good to go.